# What is wrong with my code?? or is it the editor?

Tags: python, atom-editor

i use atom editor for my python. i am self learning how to code with this book i bought. i am at loops now and when i put this code ,the code doesn't work:

```
  Names = ["joy", "darwin", "jake"]
  for name in Names:
      print(f"{name.title()}, Hi!")
```

i have tried multiple things to try to make it work and none have worked so far

i don't know why because when my friends tried it in their editors it worked fine. Is there a certain package i have to download or something??? pls i need help

Comment: Looks like something is wrong with the editor.

Comment: Can you post your error, or the exact output? Also, what is your python version? Please [edit] your post to include these details or it might be closed.

Comment: You need to remove the leading indentation from each line.

Comment: If you're new to python I definitely recommend an easier editor: PyCharm and VSCode are very intuitive. If you want to stick with atom, be sure to install a good debugger and a linter.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "the code doesn't work"? How are you running the code? what error are you seeing? what is your expected output? If you are learning to code, you should read [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and you will get much better answers.

Comment: By the way your code seems fine as long as you are running it on python version 3.6+ (that's the version fstrings were introduced in).

Answer (score 1):

Try fixing your indentation:

```
Names = ["joy", "darwin", "jake"]
for name in Names:
    print(f"{name.title()}, Hi!")
```

If this doesn't work, try changing editors.